# Empty group by and nested construct

Tags: group-by, sparql, construct

I have two questions regarding (i) group by clauses and (ii) nested construct SPARQL queries.

(i) Is it possible to formulate a SPARQL query with an empty GROUP BY clause
i.e. something like GROUP BY (), where the keyword "GROUP BY" appears in the query with an empty set of values.

(ii) Could a nested query be a "CONSTRUCT SPARQL query", the results of which will be then used in an outer SELECT clause, i.e.

```
SELECT 
WHERE {
{
CONSTRUCT ...
}
}
```

Comment: i) why? if you don't want groups, omit it ii) no

Comment: (i) You can achieve the effect (mostly) by using fixed value "GROUP BY 1" but as building that programmatically is a special case anyway, might as well omit it. (ii) No.